# Y COMO HAGO PARA QUE EL USUARIO NO INGRESE COMILLAS, ya que el MYSQL lo confunde y asume que ahi acaba la sentencia insert o update

Tags: php, mysql

sucede que tengo un input, como nombre de producto, pero no debe aceptar comillas ni simples ni dobles, ya que el mysql asume que ahi termina la sentencia en el insert o update y produce un error.
cual seria la forma de manejar este caso?
**nota:** estoy usando PHP para insertar el producto en mysql

```html
<label class="text-primary">Nombre del producto</label>
<input id="nom_prod" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="nom_prod" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="nope">
```

Comment: Hola Jos, bienvenido. Usualmente debes utilizar [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) para prevenir la inyección de código, no solo por las comillas sino porque también puede ser un problema de seguridad al ejecutar texto arbitrario.

Comment: Se llama [*Inyección SQL*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL).